# copy website in VS ultimate

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-deployment

Where is the copy website button in VS Ultimate? I want to ulpload my solution consisting of: one ASP.NET project, one Class Library, one WCF service application on somme.com free hosting. I have never deployed a web solution before, and all tutorials I saw were using copy website, bt I can't see te button. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just right click on your web project and click Publish. Choose one of the deployment options, FTP, File system, HTTP and so on, personally, I always deploy to File system (some folder on my drive) and then upload the content), and hit ok. The required files and class library dependencies will be copied.

P.S. Consider adding your class lib file as reference in your web project if you want it to be deployed with Publishing wizard. Also you should do the same for WCF service.

Comment: Thanks Davita, and after you publish to file system you just use a tool like FileZilla to upload the folder containing the solution and it works?

Comment: NP Ryian. Actually I'm using Windows Explorer as FTP Client, sometime I'm using Remote Desktop Connection to upload files. It doesn't matter at all. Main thing is that publish wizard always publishes the required project files/dependencies. you can upload that files with any tool you wish. And yes, it always works :)

Comment: Thanks. It worked for deploying the asp.net application. Then I've added a new folder called WCF, and placed in it the code I get from publishing the WCF application. But I get an error when trying to acces a service. Just try http://surveillancecamera.somee.com/WCF/Service1.svc . What is wrong here?

Comment: @Ryan I can't check the exception because customErrors attribute is set to RemoteOnly probably. Could you please disable customErrors for a while or post your exception message here so we will be able to investigate and help? thanks

Comment: Thanks @Davita. The error is probably because after deploying the ASp.NET application to the root, I've just adde a new folder called WCF and placed the WCf service application in it. Is this the way I should deploy a website? can't I deploy the whole solution? Thanks @Davita again. Hope you can help me

Comment: @Ryan, ok, now I have the error msg. "This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.". Which version of IIS are you using? Anyway you should convert your web site to web application in IIS. Right click on the web site hosted in IIS and there you should find Convert to Application or something similar, I don't remember exactly. Let me know if the problem persists after it.